# "Uncaught TypeError: 5 is not a function" при присваивании 5 в переменную

Tags: javascript

Почему данный код приводит к возникновению ошибки?

```js
var a = 5

(function() {
  // ...
})();
```

Comment: Потому что забыл `;` после 5

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до публикации вопроса.

Comment: @cppquestions, тут вопрос не опечатке... Он более глубокий... На мой взгляд...  Потому что, если бы после `5` была бы не самовызывающаяся функция, то ошибки бы не было...

Comment: @Air хорошо, отозвал тревогу

Comment: Я бы ответил, но боюсь ошибиться в мелочах... Не хочу выглядеть нехорошо...))

Comment: Потому что мода писать без точек с запятой - адовые бредни

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не ставить `;` там, где это требуется, то в некоторых ситуациях точки с запятой [будут подставлены автоматически](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9). Однако есть ситуации, в которых `;` подставлена не будет, и в итоге код будет обработан совсем не так, как планировалось.

В спецификации в разделе [7.9.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.2) есть пример, в котором `;` не будет подставлена, и который похож на пример из вопроса:

> `a = b + c`
>   `(d + e).print()`
>
> is not transformed by automatic semicolon insertion, because the parenthesised expression that begins the second line can be interpreted as an argument list for a function call:
>
> `a = b + c(d + e).print()`

В примере из вопроса суть сводится к тому, что конструкция `5(function() {...})` воспринимается как вызов функции `5` и передача ей в качестве аргумента функции. `()` же в конце воспринимается как вызов результата выполнения `5` как функции

Пример того как это выполняется (`5` заменено на `f`, потому что не очень-то получится объявить функцию с именем в виде числа):

```js
function f(func) {
  func();
  return function(number) {
    console.log(number);
  };
}

var a = f

(function() {
  console.log("func");
})(10);
```